# how to get the value in jstl

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

I have written a piece of code in jstl . I am getting the following error while executing the html.

Can I call a method in value attribute for c:set.If not please assit me how to do this.

Exception:

```
com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttributeException: /role/MyPage.xhtml @33,82 value="#{roleManager.roleStatus(roleId)}" Error Parsing: #{roleManager.roleStatus(roleId)}
```

Code:

```
<select name="123">
        <c:forEach items="#{roleManager.addRoleList}" var="category">
        <c:set var="roleId" value="#{category.value}" />
        <c:set var="roleIdValue" value="#{roleManager.getRoleStatus(roleId)}" />
            <c:if test="${roleIdValue}">
                <option value="#{roleId}" style="color:#990000;"> <h:outputLabel  value="#{category.key}" /></option>
            </c:if>
            <option value="123"> <h:outputLabel  value="#{category.key}"/></option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard el resolver cannot evaluate method invocation with parameters.
Here are some solutions:

**Using temp property in your bean:**

```
<c:set target="${roleManager}" property="roleId" value="${roleId}"/>
<c:set var="roleIdValue" value="#{roleManager.roleStatus}" />
```

Also you will need add the following code to your bean:

```
private String roleId;

public String getRoleStatus() {
    // Invocation of your logic with the parameter.
    return getRoleStatus(getRoleId());
}

public String getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}

public void setRoleId(String roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}
```

**Using functions:**

On page:

```
${prefix:methodName(param1, param2, ...)}
```

And you should declare the function in taglib:

```
<function>
<name>methodName</name>
<function-class>className</function-class>
<function-signature>
    returnType methodName(param1Type, param2Type, ...)
</function-signature>
```

As parameters you can use your roleManager itself and the argument.

**Using el-resolver which allows method invocations:**

Use for example JBoss el resolver,
or also you can implement your own solution as described here:
http://technology.amis.nl/blog/622/how-to-call-methods-from-el-expressions-pre-jsp-20-trick-for-jsps-with-jstl